# Pivot vs manual group by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I found [an article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506) commenting on the performance of pivoting using a manual GROUP BY (how it had to be done pre 11g) versus using the new [pivot clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) in 11g (which does an implicit GROUP BY itself). Here's the article's conclusion:

> “Furthermore, despite the workloads of the two methods being the same,
>   the manual pivot technique is 25% slower”

I've had a quick play and whilst my results are by no means definitive they do seem to agree with the article's (though I wasn't pivoting on multiple columns).

It would be nice if the article had done an investigation as to where the time went, particularly as the two queries have the same explain plan and cost.

*Can anyone explain why using PIVOT is faster than the manual GROUP BY?*

Comment: The problem with this question is you're asking one of two things. 1) If your question is read literally the answer is _"It's quicker because it's a native Oracle implementation and they made it quicker_". 2) If you're asking what happens behind the scenes then it's impossible to answer. Oracle is not open source so no one who hasn't worked on it will be able to answer. Equally, I imagine, that everyone who _has_ worked on this will be contractually forbidden from telling you.

Comment: So, my question is: Could you explain what answer you're looking for? Then ask yourself do you imagine anyone can answer it?

Comment: I guess I was looking for a sentence from Oracle confirming that they have indeed made it faster (even if they don't provide detail as to how). Thanks for the answer.